# wp contact form7 db plugin custom select query with where condition

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I have installed the `contactform7` with `contact form DB` plugins.

I have created the form in the name of projects. Here i have passed the post id in hidden in the name of `hid_postid`

I used the following code in the theme file

```
SELECT  submit_time, 
    DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(submit_time), '%b %e, %Y  %l:%i %p') AS Submitted,
    MAX(IF(field_name='fullname', field_value, NULL )) AS 'Name',
    MAX(IF(field_name='email', field_value, NULL )) AS 'Email',
    MAX(IF(field_name='telphone', field_value, NULL )) AS 'TelephoneNumber',
    MAX(IF(field_name='hidposttitle', field_value, NULL )) AS 'PostTitle',
    MAX(IF(field_name='hidpostid', field_value, NULL )) AS 'PostId',
    MAX(IF(field_name='hidstatus', field_value, NULL )) AS 'Status' 
    FROM wp_cf7dbplugin_submits
    WHERE
    form_name = 'Projects'  GROUP BY submit_time
    ORDER BY submit_time DESC
```

Here I want to apply the where condition as `hidpostid = 303`. I tried in many way, but nothing is worked out.

Any one help how to apply this. Thank you